# Jquery: Animating height

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to animate some elements with jQuery.
The elements have the same classes and id's since the info in the elements are 'fetched' from a database.

My problem is that when i click on the elements, all of the hidden things pop up, and i want to only show the user clicked's information. Not all of them.

In the head i got this:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#new_user").click(function() {
            $(".new_users_box").animate({height: 'toggle' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

What i am animating is this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $thumb1 = $row['user_thumb1'];
    $new_id = $row['id'];
    $new_user = $row['username'];

    echo '<a id="new_user" class="box_round"
             style="background-color:#101010 !important;">'.$new_user.'</a>
          <div class="box_newest new_users_box" style="display:none;">
             <p>'.$new_user.'</p>
          </div>';
}
```

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be referring to `$(this)` instead of `$('.new_users_box')` inside your click handler. `$(this)` will select the element that triggered the event whereas selecting a class (everything marked by a . in front) will probably select a couple of elements (which is why it will show you all of them in your case).

Comment: That does not work, then it hides the element that is clicked.

Comment: That's probably because you will need to subselect the `#new_users_box` by selecting: `$(this).children('#new_users_box').animate(..`

Comment: Ohh, i did'nt know i could select elements in an element, that really lighten things up! Thank you! :)